# Barcode scanning using react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

I am using react-native-camera to build a barcode scanner for Android and iOS both.

I am able to scan the barcode in iOS but the issue is there is no visual for the scanning boundary. And I want the whole screen to be able to scan the bar code not just the middle of the screen.

Is there any way around it?
If there is some other library that would also work for me.

Comment: you can try this approach 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45713544/1429832

Answer (score 9):

Well it took me all day but I finally found a library that worked.  If anyone finds their way here and is looking for a barcode scanner for react native that works on android...I am here to help.

https://github.com/ideacreation/react-native-barcodescanner

1st if you do not have rnpm get it...it is very helpful!(npm install -g rnpm)(https://github.com/rnpm/rnpm)

then run these commands in your project file:

> npm install --save react-native-barcodescanner
>
> rnpm link react-native-barcodescanner

at this point I synced gradle and reran the app from android studios...not sure if it is needed(also sometimes rnpm link forgets a new line character...if you have an error message about the word include it is because this...just find it in your setting.gradle file add a new line before the word include)

now it is ready to use.

import it:

```
import BarcodeScanner from 'react-native-barcodescanner';
```

then use it in your render function's return statment:

```
<BarcodeScanner
    onBarCodeRead={this._BarCodeRead}
    style={styles.preview}
    torchMode='off'
    cameraType='back'
  />
```

If you need more info check out that link.  I hope this helped someone avoid the torture I endured going through library after old library that did not work.

Happy coding! :)

Comment: Does it have highlight scanning area as well?

Comment: Does this plugin also uses the whole screen to scan barcodes?

Comment: Good questions.  I have not messed with this so I am not sure(maybe ask on the github page?).  But I know that for android this comes standard.  The above code provides a highlight area on the screen and it will only scan in that area.  I am not sure how to control it though.  good luck!

Comment: Is this  can scan all king of barcode ?  In my case it is only scanning QR codes. How to scan all kind of barcodes with the same or other library ?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using React Native Community's [React Native Camera](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera). It's quite well maintained and you can simply pass a callback prop to receive the output:

`<RNCamera onBarCodeRead={this.handleBarCodeRead}></RNCamera>`

Your callback will be invoked when a barcode is detected in the camera's view. [From the docs](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/blob/master/docs/RNCamera.md#bar-code-related-props):

> Event contains data (the data in the barcode) and type (the type of the barcode detected).

Answer (score 1):

There is a react-native library for scanning QR codes with **Highlighting scanning area** with animated **scan bar** that moves up and down.

You can use `isShowScanBar` prop to show scan bar or either disable by passing `false` to this prop.

**Github** Link https://github.com/shifeng1993/react-native-qr-scanner#readme

It's **npm** is also here https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-qr-scanner

It's **props** are listed here https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-qr-scanner#qrscanner

**Firstly,** Install the react-native-camera library as this library is dependent on it.

Just run this command in root directory of your project
 `npm i react-native-qr-scanner`

then run this `link` command `react-native link react-native-camera && react-native-qr-scanner`

Import it using :
   `import {QRscanner} from 'react-native-qr-scanner';`

```
 <QRscanner onRead={this.onRead}
    cornerBorderColor ='black'
    cornerRadius={40}
    isRepeatScan = {true}
    cornerBorderRadius={40}
    cornerColor ='black'
    scanBarColor='black'
    cornerBorderWidth={10}
    cornerBorderLength={60}
    hintText="Please Align QRCode"
    renderBottomView={this.bottomView} flashMode={this.state.flashMode}
    finderY={50}/>

 onRead = (res) => {
   alert(JSON.stringify(res))
}
```

**It works for both Android and iOS**

Answer (score 0):

[js.coach](http://js.coach) is a good place to look for react native plugins

https://github.com/ideacreation/react-native-barcodescanner

https://github.com/leofidjeland/react-native-barcode

Comment: react-native-barcode is only for generating barcode it seems. I want something to read barcodes. And using react-native-camera I am able to do this but I am having the issue I mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Just found universal code scanner - combines android and ios:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-barcode-scanner-universal

Tried on Android works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

[Expo](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v33.0.0/) provides [BarCodeScanner](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v33.0.0/sdk/bar-code-scanner) component out of the box (preinstalled in managed apps).

It works like a charm, I definitely recommend it.

You can see if `BarCodeScanner` works with your bar code, try it in snack: https://snack.expo.io/@documentation/barcodescanner-example

Comment: Expo is a great thing, but unfortunately on ios it supports only QR code.

Comment: @1011sophie, Expo on iOS supports many barcodes, not only QR. See the docs: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/bar-code-scanner/#supported-formats.
Expo's BarCodeScanner is thin wrapper for underlying iOS platform scanner, I think. It supports all barcodes that iOS supports. 
Anyone can try out BarCodeScanner if it scans their barcode from the snack: https://snack.expo.io/@documentation/barcodescanner-example