# How can I add a border frame in the camera?

Tags: react-native-camera

I need to add a square frame in the middle of the viewfinder of the react native camera view. There is not information about it in the repository also. And questions there is not being answered also.

[image: I need to make the camera view like this]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Which module you are using? `react-native-camera` or `react-native-camera-kit`?

If you using `react-native-camera` just put `View` (or `Image`) inside Camera component, then add styles to vertically and horizontally align this view.

Like this:

```js
const styles = {
    container: {
        flex: 1,
    },

    camera: {
        flex: 1,
        // These below are most important, they center your border view in container
        // ref: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center"
    },

    borderImage: {
        // Your styles for image, or custom borders
    },
}


class Component extends React.Component {

   ...

    render(){
        return <View style={styles.container}>
           <Camera style={styles.camera}>
              <Image style={styles.borderImage} source={require("./img/qrBorder.png")} />
           </Camera>
        </View>;
     }
}
```